# "access ckeditor" permission missing - buttons inactive

Tags: users, wysiwyg

I have my ckeditor basically up and running. Users with the role 'editor' however can see and use it, but the buttons appear to be inactive. Just the "Source" and "Format" are accessible for editors.

[image]

And in under permissions > ckeditor I have no permission for "access ckeditor". Any help / pointers welcome! Thank you!

ps: Editors do have permission to use the related text format "full html".

Comment: CKeditor doesn't define any such permission...traditionally you would tie CKeditor to text formats, and then set the permissions on those formats. Have you tried that?

Comment: thank you for your reply. but, as mentioned above that's exactly what i've done. The idea with that permission arose from a 'how to' article over here: http://tomandcrystal.com/how_to_set_up_the_ckeditor_module_in_drupal (under [7])

Comment: Yeah I thought as much, but maybe you hadn't set up the CKeditor profile itself and linked it to the text format (guess you have done). Not sure where that article is getting its information, you can see from [`ckeditor_permission()`](http://api.devtrac.org/api/ckeditor/ckeditor.module/function/ckeditor_permission/7.x-1.x) that there's no "access ckeditor". The way text formats and profiles are set up it wouldn't make much sense for there to be. The text format permissions should be all that's required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. I suppose it probably is some permissions problem. I now granted the "Customize CKEditor appearance" permission for the role *Editor* and the toolbar is now functional. However it leaves me puzzled why *this* paprticular permission would trigger whether a user / role is allowed to use the toolbar buttons or not.

> Customize CKEditor appearance
>
> Allow users to customize CKEditor appearance.

Either it's a wording problem and granting that permission is the right thing to to – or I now actually have granted permission to customize the CKEditor appearance (as the wording would suggest) and I have a slight security problem However – i'll submit a request for support issue over at drupal.org and edit this post once I know more…

PS: Even thought this question might leave the impression – it's not my first time on drupal. It's just the first time I'm using CKEditor instead of WYSIWYG.